# Disable IntelliJ's runtime verification of nullability

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I have a [project](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) that uses `@NotNull` and `@CanBeNull` annotations.

The tests pass when run from Maven, but some unit tests fail when run from IntelliJ with:

> Unexpected exception, expected `java.lang.NullPointerException` but was `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

It seems IntelliJ is adding code to verify the annotation's claims at run-time.

How can I disable this?

Comment: I should point out that this behaviour appears to have changed at some point, as these tests used to pass without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this in the compiler settings:

[image]